# Redux - action gets dispatched, but doesn't work with the reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've got a weird problem where I dispatch an action correctly, but the reducer doesn't get called. I'm using redux-thunk and everything is set up exactly the same how it's set up in one of my other projects. The action type matches, but nothing happens.

Also, if I put a console.log on the default case of the reducer, it gets logged 4 times every time I refresh the page, so I suppose the reducer gets loaded correctly.

```
export const submitForm = names => {
  console.log(names); //This logs what it's supposed to log every time
                      // I press the submit button
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: "SUBMIT_FORM",
      names
    });
  };
};

export default function form(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SUBMIT_FORM":
      console.log(action.names);
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        names: action.names
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

//My component is connected like this: 
const mapStateToProps = state => ({});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  formActions: bindActionCreators(formActions, dispatch)
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Comment: console.log(action.names); Please share the result of this line

Comment: It doesn't log anything. I tried console.log("test") as well and it still doesn't log anything.

Comment: If the `reducer` loads on initial load, and you are getting this issue, you might want to check `action` param in the `reducer`

Comment: Does console.log(names) get called, and how you use the submit form function, how do you connect your component? You need to add these to question

Comment: This is what gets logged if I log the action param. I suppose this is correct? https://imgur.com/a/3LgTsKp

Comment: @ÇağataySel I have updated my question

Comment: I am using redux 6 hooks now, so I am not 100 % sure how `mapState…` should look like, but `const mapStateToProps = state => ({})` looks suspicious to me: it returns an empty object. Don't you mean `const mapStateToProps = state => {}` aka `noop` instead?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a little strange to me that an `action creator` returns a function. `Action creators`normally `return` an action, that is, an `object`. `Async action creators` returns `functions`. So, you can try refactor your `action creator` that will `return a objetct`, and then you pass the action creator to the dispatch as an argument.

```js
export const submitForm = names => {
  console.log(names); //This logs what it's supposed to log every time
                      // I press the submit button
  return {
      type: "SUBMIT_FORM",
      names
    }
};

dispatch(submitForm(names));
```

Besides that, according to [react-redux.js.org/mapdispatch](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch) to use `bindActionCreators` in `mapDispatchToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` does not return an object, but does return `bindActionCreators`.

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => 
  bindActionCreators(formActions, dispatch);
```

another point, if you need to pass an argument to your `action creator` I would do like this:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  submitForm: (names) => dispatch(submitForm(names))
});
```

Unfortunately, I can't see all of your code. I hope I helped you with something.

Comment: I am using middleware called `thunk` that makes it possible to return a function instead of an action. The dispatch is a part of that library. I have tried returning only the action to rule out problems with the middleware, but that didn't work.

Comment: I know about `redux-thunk`. Using `redux-thunk` you can return a `function` instead of an `object` and this `function` don't need to be pure like reducers functions. I said that is weird use the `async action creator`  for no reason.

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope that now is enough for you :)

Comment: All of  that is really nice, but it literally has nothing to do with my question and problem and doesn't solve literally anything. This part of my app works correctly and always has worked this way.